# Logstash - JSON parse list

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

I'm really liking ELK for parsing the logs. However, I'm stuck at a point where it needs to parse a list of dictionaries. Following are my logs:-

```
IP - - 0.000 0.000 [24/May/2015:06:51:13 +0000] *"POST /c.gif HTTP/1.1"* 200 4 * user_id=UserID&package_name=SomePackageName&model=Titanium+S202&country_code=in&android_id=AndroidID&eT=1432450271859&eTz=GMT%2B05%3A30&events=%5B%7B%22eV%22%3A%22com.olx.southasia%22%2C%22eC%22%3A%22appUpdate%22%2C%22eA%22%3A%22app_activated%22%2C%22eTz%22%3A%22GMT%2B05%3A30%22%2C%22eT%22%3A%221432386324909%22%2C%22eL%22%3A%22packageName%22%7D%5D * "-" "-" "-"
```

The URL decoded version of the above log is

```
IP - - 0.000 0.000 [24/May/2015:06:51:13  0000] *"POST /c.gif HTTP/1.1"* 200 4 * user_id=UserID&package_name=SomePackageName&model=Titanium S202&country_code=in&android_id=AndroidID&eT=1432450271859&eTz=GMT+05:30&events=[{"eV":"com.olx.southasia","eC":"appUpdate","eA":"app_activated","eTz":"GMT+05:30","eT":"1432386324909","eL":"packageName"}] * "-" "-" "-"
```

Wherever I try to parse it, it shows me `_jsonparsefailure`. I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753921/logstash-does-not-parse-json) question as well, and has gone through various forums as well, but didnt find a perfect solution for the same. How can I parse a json list in logstash?? If there **doesnt exist** any till now, what can be the work around for the same.??

Following is my config file.

```
filter {
    mutate {
        gsub => [
            "message", "\+", "%20"
        ]
    }

    urldecode{
        field => "message"
    }
    grok {
        match => [
            'message', '%{IP:clientip}%{GREEDYDATA} \[%{GREEDYDATA:timestamp}\] \*"%{WORD:method}%{GREEDYDATA}'
        ]
    }

    kv {
        field_split => "&?"
    }

    json{
        source => "events"
    }

    geoip {
        source => "clientip"
    }
}
```

Comment: The kv{} filter should make you a field called "events" which contains your json.  Does it?

Comment: Yes, It does. But that does not parse the list values of `events`

Comment: I understand that, but if the kv{} doesn't work, the json{} wouldn't have any input to process.  If you take the value of "event" after the kv{} filter to a json validator, is it ok?

Comment: Yes, that is ok. The json filter successfully parses a json in the form of `{ "foo":"bar" }`
The json that it is unable to parse is `[ { "foo":"bar" } ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is an exact copy of [Parse json in a list in logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782160/parse-json-in-a-list-in-logstash). Even with the same log entries?! Could anyone make sense of that?

You can see my answer there but I will sum it up for you... **option e) is probably the best approach**

---

Apparently you get a *jsonparsefailure* because of the square brackets. As a workaround you could manually remove them. Add the following mutate filter after your kv and before your json filter:

```
mutate  {
    gsub => [ "events","\]",""]
    gsub => [ "events","\[",""]
}
```

However, that doesn't work for an input like `[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"bar1"}]`. So here are 4 options:

**Option a) ugly gsub**

An ugly workaround would be another gsub:

```
gsub => [ "event","\},\{",","]
```

But this would remove the inner relations so I guess you don't want to do that.

**Option b) split**

A better approach might be to use the split filter:

```
split {
    field => "event"
    terminator => ","
}
mutate  {
    gsub => [ "event","\]",""]
    gsub => [ "event","\[",""]
   }
json{
    source=> "event"
}
```

This would generate multiple events. (First with `foo = bar` and second with `foo1 = bar1`.)

**Option c) mutate split**

You might want to have all the values in one logstash event. You could use the mutate => split filter to generate an array and parse the json if an entry exists. Unfortunately you will have to set a conditional for each entry because logstash doesn't support loops in its config.

```
mutate  {
    gsub => [ "event","\]",""]
    gsub => [ "event","\[",""]
    split => [ "event", "," ]
   }

json{
    source=> "event[0]"
    target => "result[0]"
}

if 'event[1]' {
    json{
        source=> "event[1]"
        target => "result[1]"
    }
    if 'event[2]' {
        json{
            source=> "event[2]"
            target => "result[2]"
        }
    }
    # You would have to specify more conditionals if you expect even more dictionaries
}
```

**Option d) Ruby1**

<strike>Following works (after your kv filter):</strike> Rather use option e)

```
mutate  {
    gsub => [ "event","\]",""]
    gsub => [ "event","\[",""]
}

ruby  {
    init => "require 'json'"
    code => "
        e = event['event'].split(',')
        ary = Array.new
        e.each do |x|
            hash = JSON.parse(x)
            hash.each do |key, value|
                ary.push( { key =>  value } )
            end
        end
        event['result'] = ary
    "
}
```

---

### UPDATE

**Option e) Ruby2**

After some testing this might be the best approach. Use this after your kv filter:

```
ruby  {
    init => "require 'json'"
    code => "event['result'] = JSON.parse(event['event'])"
}
```