# How to loop logstash event recursively

Tags: ruby, logstash

I have following situation.

I receive json encoded object in logstash and decode it, like

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        target => "json"
    }
}
```

So I have json object with complex nested structure.
Now I need to parse json object and remove all fields with special name.

For example removing "BinaryData" fields:

```
event
- json
--...
--- BinaryData: ... <- remove
```

The problem is that BinaryData can be anywhere, on any nested level, and I need to traverse event recursively somehow.

Any ideas how to do that?

PS Don't suggest gsub as solution.
PPS Suggesting ruby code please provide any recursive example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse json in a list in logstash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782160/parse-json-in-a-list-in-logstash)

Comment: @anquegi How is it duplicate? absolutely different questions.

Comment: Well I think that you should read that other question answer to fix your solution, maybe I wrong